# React Native update third party automatically after npm install

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am a newbie on react native.
Is it possible to setup the correct sdk version or other things for the third party library automatically after npm install? Because sometimes when i mess up the project and the code cannot be rolled back, i will remove it and clone the project from git. But that is the problem, because the android library sdk version and ios library search path are incorrect, i need to correct them by myself.

Comment: You can add postinstall script in the npm and create a bash script where it replaces the paths with awk or sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `postinstall` into the package.json scripts. This will be run automatically after install has ran:

`"postinstall": "./edit_modules.sh",`

And create an `edit_modules.sh` file in project root directory. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    SED_CMD="sed -i ''"
else
    SED_CMD="sed -i"
fi

$SED_CMD 's/<pattern to find>/<replace with>/' <path to file relative to root>
```

The if/else for `sed` is because it has different signature on macos and linux.

And example sed we have in our project:

```
$SED_CMD 's/#import <fishhook\/fishhook.h>/#import "fishhook.h"/' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTReconnectingWebSocket.m
```

Comment: i change the scripts to "postinstall": "sh ./edit_modules.sh" and add
"config": {"unsafe-perm": true} . Then run sudo npm install --unsafe-perm , is work for me . But the original file name is changed to {build.gradle''}  and there is the new file is created {build.gradle} , is it right?

Comment: No it's not right. Create the file with the bash script. Set permissions for the file: `sudo chmod +x yourfile.sh`. Then try to execute it with `bash yourfile.sh`. If it runs without permission denied then ok. If not then try chmod with +X (capital x) or `sudo chmod 775`. Not sure now, it may vary of linux/mac/win distro. If you want to check permissions for the file run in commnad terminal in root project dir `ls -la | grep yourfile.sh` and on the left you should see `-rwxr-xr-x` if there is an x 3 times it means can be executed by anyone.

Comment: Then try to run install. It should not create a new gradle file, it should just edit the line defined in `sed`.

Comment: i have follow your instructions, set permission for the file sudo chmod 775 edit_modules.sh , the permission now is -rwxrwxr-x, it is work too, but still create the new gradle file

Comment: So back to the root problem, you have 3rd party module, with native ios and android, but the paths added to project after install are wrong. paths for the source code of these modules. You need to manually edit the build files, replace he wrong path for the correct one. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe i post the final result here.

1. Set up the script
https://i.stack.imgur.com/atLkG.png
2. Put the edit_modules.sh file in project root directory
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLs8m.png
3. Add postinstall into the package.json scripts
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5XBi.png
4. run "npm install" and the result is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PlW4.png

Comment: I have no idea what is happening, but after i change the script like this https://imgur.com/vNaAeHD , the file is not backup and replace the original file as what i need right now.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Maybe some terminal guru will answer in that. I am glad that the shell for edit works for you at the end :)

Comment: That is save my day, because most of the android libraries which are set to the lower sdk, i can not run the project. But i have facing another issue, how can i add the new line? Because the gradle can not build [Image](https://imgur.com/a/H1zfU83) like this in the same line

Comment: @Ivan1022 I can't get the answer from top of my head at the moment, but I faced this before. If you look I am sure you can find an answer on gradle dependecy versions in here.